# what can I do for converting infix to prefix?

Tags: java, stack, prefix, infix-notation

I write this block of code to convert infix to prefix but I don't get any output what can I do ?

when the last while running it get into infinity loop and the if conditions don't process what is the problem?

```
 static String infixToPrefix(String infix){
        for (int j = 0; j < infix.length(); j++){
            if (infix.charAt(j) == 's' && infix.charAt(j + 1) == 'i' && infix.charAt(j + 2) == 'n'){
                infix = infix.replace("sin","S");
                break;
            }
            else if (infix.charAt(j) == 'c' && infix.charAt(j + 1) == 'o' && infix.charAt(j + 2) == 's' ){
                infix = infix.replace("cos", "C");
                break;
            }
            else if (infix.charAt(j) == 't' && infix.charAt(j + 1) == 'a' && infix.charAt(j + 2) == 'n' ) {
                infix = infix.replace("tan", "T");
                break;
            }
            else if (infix.charAt(j) == 'l' && infix.charAt(j + 1) == 'o' && infix.charAt(j + 2) == 'g' ) {
                infix = infix.replace("log", "L");
                break;
            }
        }
        Stack<String> operators = new Stack<>();
        Stack<String> operands = new Stack<>();
        String[] exp = infix.split("");
        for (int i = 0; i < exp.length; i++) {
            if (exp[i].equals("(")) {
                operators.push(exp[i]);
            }
            else if (exp[i].equals(")")) {
                while (!operators.isEmpty() && !operators.getTop().equals("(")) {
                    if (isMultiOperator(operators.getTop())){
                        String op1 = operands.getTop();
                        operands.pop();

                        String op2 = operands.getTop();
                        operands.pop();

                        String op3 = operators.getTop();
                        operators.pop();

                        String temp = op3 + op2 + op1;
                        operands.push(temp);
                    }
                    else if(isUnaryOperator(operators.getTop())){
                        String op1 = operands.getTop();
                        operands.pop();

                        String op2 = operators.getTop();
                        operators.pop();

                        String temp = op2 + op1;
                        operands.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                operators.pop();
            }
            else if (isMultiOperator(exp[i]) || isUnaryOperator(exp[i])){

                while (!(operators.isEmpty()) && precedence(exp[i]) <= precedence(operators.getTop())) {

                    if (isMultiOperator(operators.getTop())){
                        String op1 = operands.getTop();
                        operands.pop();

                        String op2 = operands.getTop();
                        operands.pop();

                        String op3 = operators.getTop();
                        operators.pop();

                        String temp = op3 + op2 + op1;
                        operands.push(temp);
                    }
                    else if (isUnaryOperator(operators.getTop())){
                        String op1 = operands.getTop();
                        operands.pop();

                        String op2 = operators.getTop();
                        operators.pop();

                        String temp = op2 + op1;
                    }
                }
                operators.push(exp[i] + " ");
            }
            else if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(infix.charAt(i))){
                boolean haveDot = exp[i].equals(".");
                String temp = haveDot ? "0." : exp[i];
                while ((i + 1) < exp.length && (Character.isLetterOrDigit(infix.charAt(i + 1)) || exp[i + 1].equals("."))) {
                    temp += exp[i + 1];
                    i++;
                }
                operands.push(temp + " ");
            }
        }
        while (!operators.isEmpty()){
            if (isMultiOperator(operators.getTop())){
                String op1 = operands.getTop();
                operands.pop();

                String op2 = operands.getTop();
                operands.pop();

                String op3 = operators.getTop();
                operators.pop();

                String temp = op3 + op2 + op1;
                operands.push(temp);
            }
            else if (isUnaryOperator(operators.getTop())){
                String op1 = operands.getTop();
                operands.pop();

                String op2 = operators.getTop();
                operators.pop();

                String temp = op2 + op1;
                operands.push(temp);
            }
        }
        return operands.getTop() ;
    }
```

I write this block of code to convert infix to prefix but I don't get any output what can I do ?
when the last while running it get into infinity loop and the if conditions don't process what is the problem?

Comment: Start by single-stepping the program in your debugger. That will let you see where things are going wrong. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to learn.

Comment: I perfectly do that but still I don't know what is going wrong can you help to know please ?!